# unable to convert to innodb from myisam

Tags: php, mysql, innodb, myisam

i was trying to convert myisam table to innodb as i was frustrated with myisam table level of lock and i was in desperate need to solve this issue.  i tried from phpmyadmin and chosen the engine from dropdown to innodb and clicked on go but i am getting this error.in my table there are 5 million rows.

```
   SQL query: Edit Edit

     ALTER TABLE `tableA`
       ENGINE = InnoDB;

    MySQL said: Documentation
    #1071 - Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes
```

is there any way i can convert table by choosing 100 row at a time so that if i run that code/scripts several time entire table will be converted to innodb.

please guide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your primary key columns are too long for InnoDB. First alter the length of the  Primary Key columns of this table to something reasonable according to what data you store.

Comment: i have two primary key one is id which is autoincrement and other is title i tried to remove title from primary key but getting error ., i run this code to change primary key alter table `tableA` drop primary key

Comment: What is the length of Primaery Keys set to? Also, you cannot have any `TEXT` primary keys/indexes in InnoDB.

Comment: yes title column is text so i should change that to varchar?

Comment: now only one key is there id int(10) then also i am getting that error